# Kubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver release files

Tags: lts, 18.04

(I'm a newbie linux user) Ok, we all know that Canonical has not yet officially released the Bionic Beaver on their website. I just couldn't wait and I went into the index of the website and found the file and found it in these two pages which are in different directories:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/bionic/release/
(Two different directories: 18.04 and bionic)

But the download buttons point to the same file link:

http://d3as07rf8ax8k6.cloudfront.net/kubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Is this image a stable build? Or is it a beta build?

Comment: a more general question would be: "Is there a way to determine the buildversion from a *ubuntu-iso."

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is already [officially released](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), so the image you linked is a stable build. Even Beta images from development branches join the stable release with the last update.

*Note: since you're a new user it's probably worth mentioning that the image you linked is an [official flavor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors), not the original Ubuntu that comes with Ubuntu-desktop.*